Cmake generation failed due to a config error in FindPythonLibsNew.cmake
I am trying to download a repo to configure and build in visual studios, this is the first time I have done such a thing and have no clue what I'm doing. Here is the documentation for the repo : https://alabamaasrl.github.io/asset_asrl/
When opening the repo in VS, there is an error saying "Cmake generation failed", and the debug says:
CMake Error at dep/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:147 (message):
  Python config failure:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dep/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
  dep/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
  dep/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:208 (include)

I have tried a few things and I'm at a loss. Would this be a problem with VS, the repo, maybe my anaconda didn't download correctly? Something wrong with the path or system variables?
The repo is dependent upon Intel oneAPI MKL, LLVM, and VS, and recommends downloading anaconda. Perhaps I downloaded one of these incorrectly? I have not written or modified any of the code in the repo, so all of that should be fine.
